# prevention of bots automating payment process in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, credit-card, bots

I have a .net c# web application that allows users to purchase products.

My site has a payment page, with input fields etc.

I have had some attacks recently via bots automating the submit of payments just to validate credit card authorization.

So I need to change my page so that bots cant do this. So I am looking at advice as to do this? I have started by changing the field names so that they are different each time to page loads, via a hash. Any other tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand that you are trying to find a solution which does not involve human interaction in order to keep the user experience as good as possible.

Since the evil-doers are using your site to check credit card validity you are probably dealing with a more targeted misuse of your resources as opposed to common blocking scenarios for automated processes, like comment spam bots and alike. Depending on how valuable "your service" is to the people who are exploiting your website, locking them out without requiring human interaction might only work until they figured out what you changed.

Alternating field names aren't going to stop them from populating the fields by order of appearance on your site, for example.

Solutions like having javascript populate a hidden form field are only good as long the bot does not speak javascript.

I would suggest to use all the techniques found when searching for captcha alternatives and use the methods in random combinations for each request - then hope that another site is less secured so they start using a different site to get what they need.

If all doesn't help you can still use a solution that involves human interaction.

Answer (score 1):

[CAPTCHA](http://www.captcha.net/) will help to stop this. It will require the user to complete a validation check before the page will go through. Here is a [sample implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/CaptchaControl.aspx) of how CAPTCHA can be implemented in ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

A "captcha" is the standard way of preventing bot submitted forms. [Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) is free, works well and is actually helping to scan books through its use.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following approach once and it gave me good results.

In short the idea is to create an invisible field, name it so that the robot could easily understand it and, on the server side, check the value of this field. If it is populated, than it was definitely a robot and you can safely ignore this request. 
For example:

1. Rename your FirstName field to, say, EmanTsrif.
2. Add another field <input id="FirstName" class="trap_for_robots">.
3. Define css class trap_for_robots: {display: none} (preferable in a standalone .css file - don't use style="display:none"!).
4. In your codebehind check if (FirstName.Text != "") { //do nothing, log something }.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax control kit has a "NoBot" control you can use.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/NoBot/NoBot.aspx

Comment: I prefer an approach like this without user interaction.

Comment: Looking at this control, this is based on a server side postback. I am calling a wcf service via jquery, how could i integrate this control in to this here?

Comment: You won't. You didn't mention these kinds of details anywhere in the question or tags, so I assumed you had a standard asp.net webforms application.

Answer (score 0):

Have look on this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) , read the "Technical measures to stop bots" section, it gives a number of measures to stop bots.